# How to insert auto value into (CMD) using PHP through default value?

Tags: php, cmd, command-line

i was trying to insert input into command line using php
so what i did and what i have

what i have i have a php code to read input from the customer via comman line
when he run it via cmd line php filename.php
it will ask for input from him and  click enter 
so what i'm trying to do i wanna to fill that line from php when the customer doesn't fill it after 3 second it fill auto 
[image]
so this is the code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);
class logincustom
{

    public function readline($pesan)
    {
        echo "[Year Checker] " . $pesan;
        $answer =  rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
        return $answer;
    }



    public  function run()
    {


        $from = $this->readline("Year From : "); // this is what i wanna it to input from here if the customer did not input it after 3 second
        $to = $this->readline("Year To : "); // this is what i wanna it to input from here if the customer did not input it after 3 second
        if ($from > $to) die("Wrong number.");
        for ($i = (int) $from; $i <= (int) $to; $i++) {
            $year = sprintf("%03d", $i);

            if ($year == 2026) {
                echo "hello there";
            } else {
                // system(cls);
                echo "wrong input \n\r" . exec(cls);
                $this->run();
            }
        }
    }
}
$logincustom = new logincustom;
$logincustom->run();
```